# Analysing Input in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have an array of mixed types (integers and doubles).
I need to read through the  lines of the input values.

I was trying to store the first two values of rows 2~11 as an array and 4th~13th values of the same rows as a 10*10 array

I wanted to pass them into a C compiler and use a printf function to print out the values. However, I had trouble storing the values and got an error "incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'int [10][2]'", when I tried store the doubles to find average of (73.29 77.35 66.66 44.12 49.65 60.72 78.76 29.45 15.16 35.70 ) in the second rom

These are the input values.

```
10

104 80 34.31 73.29 77.35 66.66 44.12 49.65 60.72 78.76 29.45 15.16 35.70 106 121 114
106 90 49.36 49.33 47.02 40.86 46.57 49.04 49.77 40.75 49.54 42.33 43.42 124 -1
114 90 80.85 81.50 66.26 84.71 50.63 17.01 70.02 54.95 82.38 28.54 69.71 132 -1
121 60 33.65 10.47 51.25 57.63 13.60 44.24 17.20 33.32 24.15 29.60 24.25 201 -1
124 40 31.13 36.52 24.10 29.71 28.05 16.02 32.55 15.17 36.31 30.95 20.39 221 351 -1
132 60 29.42 15.55 30.03 29.92 22.67 21.25 11.80 23.48 25.30 23.52 22.90 121 797 -1
201 80 43.27 06.62 10.43 12.28 21.59 32.42 22.72 22.11 27.61 21.36 27.77 -1
221 50 24.16 48.13 44.73 43.19 49.57 47.68 39.90 49.93 45.13 45.58 41.50 -1
351 90 77.83 86.72 82.94 85.29 85.66 85.58 81.95 84.71 88.00 89.49 84.69 104 797 -1
797 40 22.11 20.26 26.67 24.44 27.17 27.29 22.07 24.14 20.30 10.67 24.16 -1
0.6 0.8
```

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

       int rows;
    int location_ID, speed_lim;
    double latest_ave_speed;
    double historical_speed[10];
    double location_details[10][2];
    
    //for scanning the traffic data
    int val;
    double speed;// each of the speed values recorded
    //fiugre out the number of rows of locations

    scanf("%d" ,&rows);
    //reading each line
    //the first three vals 
    
    while (scanf("%d %d %lf", &location_ID, &speed_lim, &latest_ave_speed )== 3){
        //get the location details
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

            for(int j=0; j<2; j++){
                location_details[i][j]= scanf("%d",&val);


            }

            return location_details;

            for(int j=3; j<12; j++){

                historical_speed[j-3] =scanf("%lf", &speed);

                merged_historical_speed(historical_speed);
            

                
            }
```

I was trying to re-arrange the data into a 10X2 integer array to store the first two integers of rows 2~11 and a 10X10 array to sore the 3rd ~12th columns of these rows to return the average of the doubles.

Comment: After adding some trivial markup to show the input values clearly, it appears these are not all the same length. Please check the source data you've posted.

Comment: scanf may be useful if your input is well formatted.  Since your input lines differ in the number of entries, your input is not really "well formatted".  (It is somewhat difficult to distinguish between a newline and a space with scanf).  scanf could be used to parse this input, but as is usually the case, it is almost certainly the wrong tool.

Comment: Why is there a return statement in the middle of the loop?

Comment: `location_details[i][j]= scanf("%d",&val);` does not make much sense.  Especially since `scanf` returns an `int`, but `location_details[i][j]` is declared to be of type double.  What are you trying to do here?  `scanf` is going to return either 0, 1, or EOF.

Comment: @WilliamPursell. Oops. I made the wrong declaration at the beginning. I was tryig to store the scanned integer value and store it into a 10X2 array.

Comment: @stark. Oh. I was combining two for loops together and got myself mixed up with the return statement

Comment: `scanf` does not return the value that it reads.  It returns either the number of values it successfully read (which are stored in the locations passed as arguments to `scanf`) or the value EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Please post a complete program.

You will not pass your data *into a `C` compiler*. You will pass your data to this `C` program.

Sure, we can say you have an array of mixed types, but it seems that you have a set of data readings with a pre-defined format, like

- location id
- speed limit
- latest speed average
- 10 new speed readings
- some additional data, not used yet or ever

Also it seems that you want to get the average value of the readings.

If there were dozens of fields the easy way is to write a simple function parser with a loop that builds each record and an inner loop that gets each field.

Since there are only 13 fields we can use a simple `scanf` or `sscanf` call.

**I will show a small example here, source, output and some comments included.**

### Edit

I added a second function print function, `so_show_points` to print the input data, formatted. The 2 printing functions are called in this example below.

#### `CSV` files and `scanf`

`scanf` --- and the family of scanners like `sscanf` used here --- were written to consume tabular data like the input file here.

This call

```
    int res = sscanf(
      ln, mask, &one->location_id, &one->speed_limit,
      &one->latest_average, &one->reading[0],
      &one->reading[1], &one->reading[2],
      &one->reading[3], &one->reading[4],
      &one->reading[5], &one->reading[6],
      &one->reading[7], &one->reading[8],
      &one->reading[9]);
  if (res != 13)
//...
```

shows how it can consume a full line of the input file here, parsing data, converting types and skipping unused fields. The `mask` used was

```
    const char* mask =
        "\
%d %d %lf\
%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\
 %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf";
```

I added a function, `so_build_mask()`. This one is not used in the examples. This function returns a mask for a declared number of fields. It is here just to show that it can be computed at *runtine*, not at compile time. A line like

```
        const char* mask = build_mask(10);
```

returns an identical `mask` as the one used in the example. See a possible implementation:

```
const char* so_build_mask(unsigned n)
{
    if (n == 0) return NULL;
    const char*  prefix = "%d %d %lf";
    char*        field  = " %lf";
    const size_t size =
        1 + sizeof(prefix) + n * sizeof(" %lf");
    char* mask = malloc(size);
    strcpy(mask, prefix);
    if (mask == NULL) return NULL;
    char*  p   = mask + 1 + sizeof(prefix);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        char* pf = field;
        do {
            *p++ = *pf++;
        } while (*pf != 0);
    };
    *p = 0;  // terminate string 'mask'
    return mask;
}
```

### end of edit

**write around your data:** as far as your code goes from the data the harder it get it done. Your data record seems to be

```
typedef struct
{
    int    location_id;
    int    speed_limit;
    double latest_average;
    double reading[10];
    double avg;
} Speed_data;
```

Since the average seems to be needed it can be calculated as the data is read and then saved inside the struct. Or not. In this example I saved it.

And there a bunch of records, like in

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned    size;
    Speed_data* rcd;
    unsigned    n_readings;  // 10 here
} Data_set;
```

Always go for **encapsulation** of your data. OOP has its value...

- No counters spread around the code
- no pointers floating around
- data treated as a whole
- no functions with dozens of arguments

And there is an input file as described... A good start is to consider a program like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    const char* in_file = "data.txt";
    FILE*       in      = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    fprintf(stderr, "    '%s' open\n", in_file);
    char  line[250] = {0};
    char* p         = line;  // p points to line
    p               = fgets(line, sizeof(line), in);
    if (p == NULL) return -2;  // read nothing
    const int N = atoi(line);
    if (N < 1) return -3;
    fprintf(stderr, "    Reading %d lines of data\n", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), in);
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "    Error after after reading %d lines\n",
                i);
            break;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%4d %s", i, line);
    }
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

It is good to know that the data is being read as expected, the whole input file is consumed and so on...

#### output of this program

**About the input file used in this example:**

- I added 2 lines to the original input file:

  - one with all readings 0.
  - one with all reading 1.0.
- I changed all readings at the last line to have value above 100

```
    'data.txt' open
    Reading 12 lines of data
   0 104 80 34.31 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 121 114
   1 104 80 34.31 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 121 114
   2 104 80 34.31 73.29 77.35 66.66 44.12 49.65 60.72 78.76 29.45 15.16 35.70 106 121 114
   3 106 90 49.36 49.33 47.02 40.86 46.57 49.04 49.77 40.75 49.54 42.33 43.42 124 -1
   4 114 90 80.85 81.50 66.26 84.71 50.63 17.01 70.02 54.95 82.38 28.54 69.71 132 -1
   5 121 60 33.65 10.47 51.25 57.63 13.60 44.24 17.20 33.32 24.15 29.60 24.25 201 -1
   6 124 40 31.13 36.52 24.10 29.71 28.05 16.02 32.55 15.17 36.31 30.95 20.39 221 351 -1
   7 132 60 29.42 15.55 30.03 29.92 22.67 21.25 11.80 23.48 25.30 23.52 22.90 121 797 -1
   8 201 80 43.27 06.62 10.43 12.28 21.59 32.42 22.72 22.11 27.61 21.36 27.77 -1
   9 221 50 24.16 48.13 44.73 43.19 49.57 47.68 39.90 49.93 45.13 45.58 41.50 -1
  10 351 90 77.83 86.72 82.94 85.29 85.66 85.58 81.95 84.71 88.00 89.49 84.69 104 797 -1
  11 797 40 122.11 120.26 126.67 124.44 127.17 127.29 122.07 124.14 120.30 110.67 124.16 -1
```

Now we save this program and proceed.

#### now we can read the data, and we have `Data_set` to save it

Consider the example program above and a function like

```
        Speed_data* so_cnvrt(const char* ln);
```

That could convert a line from input into a `struct` `Speed_data` with the correct fields and the computed average.

Consider also functions

```
    int       so_show(Data_set*, const char*);
    int       so_show_points(Data_set*, const char*);
```

That could print a full data_set as in the input file

- `so_show` prints only

  - location id
  - speed limit
  - latest average
  - computed average
- `so_show_points` prints also all speed data

Both functions accepts a handy optional message that is printed exatcly as received. This is to avoid the classic `printf` calls in testing ;)

So this `main.c` could work:

```
int main(void)
{
    // open file
    const char* in_file = "data.txt";
    FILE*       in      = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    fprintf(stderr, "    '%s' open\n", in_file);
    char  line[250] = {0};
    char* p         = NULL;

    // get size of input
    p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), in);
    if (p == NULL) return -2;  // read nothing
    const int N = atoi(line);
    if (N < 1) return -3;

    // create array
    Data_set* data = so_create_ds(N);
    if (data == NULL) return -4;

    // process input
    fprintf(
        stderr, "    Reading %d lines of data\n    ", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), in);
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr, "    No data after %d lines\n", i);
            so_destroy_ds(data);
            fclose(in);
            return -5;
        }
        Speed_data* one = so_cnvrt(line);
        if (NULL == one)  // read error
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr, "    Error after %d lines\n", i);
            free(one);
            so_destroy_ds(data);
            fclose(in);
            return -6;
        }
        data->rcd[i] = *one;  // shallow copy
        free(one);            // copied already
    }
    fclose(in);
    so_show(data, "\n[Average]");
    so_show_points(data, "\n[Speed readings]");
    so_destroy_ds(data);
    return 0;
}  // end main
```

It is a matter of copy and paste from the first program. Would it work?

#### output of the second program

```
    'data.txt' open
    Reading 12 lines of data

[Average]    12 lines in this set:

|-----------------------------------------------|
|          |          |         average         |
|    loc   |    lim   |    latest  |   actual   |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|    104   |     80   |    34.31   |      1.00  |
|    104   |     80   |    34.31   |      0.00  |
|    104   |     80   |    34.31   |     53.09  |
|    106   |     90   |    49.36   |     45.86  |
|    114   |     90   |    80.85   |     60.57  |
|    121   |     60   |    33.65   |     30.57  |
|    124   |     40   |    31.13   |     26.98  |
|    132   |     60   |    29.42   |     22.64  |
|    201   |     80   |    43.27   |     20.49  |
|    221   |     50   |    24.16   |     45.53  |
|    351   |     90   |    77.83   |     85.50  |
|    797   |     40   |   122.11   |    122.72  |
|-----------------------------------------------|


[Speed readings]    12 lines in this set:

|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     |     |      average    |                                                                                         |
| loc | lim | latest | actual | s p e e d   r e a d i n g s                                                             |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 104 |  80 |  34.31 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |   1.00 |
| 104 |  80 |  34.31 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |   0.00 |
| 104 |  80 |  34.31 |  53.09 |  73.29 |  77.35 |  66.66 |  44.12 |  49.65 |  60.72 |  78.76 |  29.45 |  15.16 |  35.70 |
| 106 |  90 |  49.36 |  45.86 |  49.33 |  47.02 |  40.86 |  46.57 |  49.04 |  49.77 |  40.75 |  49.54 |  42.33 |  43.42 |
| 114 |  90 |  80.85 |  60.57 |  81.50 |  66.26 |  84.71 |  50.63 |  17.01 |  70.02 |  54.95 |  82.38 |  28.54 |  69.71 |
| 121 |  60 |  33.65 |  30.57 |  10.47 |  51.25 |  57.63 |  13.60 |  44.24 |  17.20 |  33.32 |  24.15 |  29.60 |  24.25 |
| 124 |  40 |  31.13 |  26.98 |  36.52 |  24.10 |  29.71 |  28.05 |  16.02 |  32.55 |  15.17 |  36.31 |  30.95 |  20.39 |
| 132 |  60 |  29.42 |  22.64 |  15.55 |  30.03 |  29.92 |  22.67 |  21.25 |  11.80 |  23.48 |  25.30 |  23.52 |  22.90 |
| 201 |  80 |  43.27 |  20.49 |   6.62 |  10.43 |  12.28 |  21.59 |  32.42 |  22.72 |  22.11 |  27.61 |  21.36 |  27.77 |
| 221 |  50 |  24.16 |  45.53 |  48.13 |  44.73 |  43.19 |  49.57 |  47.68 |  39.90 |  49.93 |  45.13 |  45.58 |  41.50 |
| 351 |  90 |  77.83 |  85.50 |  86.72 |  82.94 |  85.29 |  85.66 |  85.58 |  81.95 |  84.71 |  88.00 |  89.49 |  84.69 |
| 797 |  40 | 122.11 | 122.72 | 120.26 | 126.67 | 124.44 | 127.17 | 127.29 | 122.07 | 124.14 | 120.30 | 110.67 | 124.16 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

It works. Or it seems to work.

#### complete `C` code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int    location_id;
    int    speed_limit;
    double latest_average;
    double reading[10];
    double avg;
} Speed_data;

Speed_data* so_cnvrt(const char*);  // 1 line => 1 record

typedef struct
{
    unsigned    size;
    Speed_data* rcd;
    unsigned    n_readings;  // 10 here
} Data_set;

Data_set* so_create_ds(unsigned);
Data_set* so_destroy_ds(Data_set*);
int       so_show(Data_set*, const char*);
int       so_show_points(Data_set*, const char*);

const char* so_build_mask(unsigned n);

int main(void)
{
    // open file
    const char* in_file = "data.txt";
    FILE*       in      = fopen(in_file, "r");
    if (in == NULL) return -1;
    fprintf(stderr, "    '%s' open\n", in_file);
    char  line[250] = {0};
    char* p         = NULL;

    // get size of input
    p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), in);
    if (p == NULL) return -2;  // read nothing
    const int N = atoi(line);
    if (N < 1) return -3;

    // create array
    Data_set* data = so_create_ds(N);
    if (data == NULL) return -4;

    // process input
    fprintf(
        stderr, "    Reading %d lines of data\n    ", N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += 1)
    {
        p = fgets(line, sizeof(line), in);
        if (p == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr, "    No data after %d lines\n", i);
            so_destroy_ds(data);
            fclose(in);
            return -5;
        }
        Speed_data* one = so_cnvrt(line);
        if (NULL == one)  // read error
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr, "    Error after %d lines\n", i);
            free(one);
            so_destroy_ds(data);
            fclose(in);
            return -6;
        }
        data->rcd[i] = *one;  // shallow copy
        free(one);            // copied already
    }
    fclose(in);
    so_show(data, "\n[Average]");
    so_show_points(data, "\n[Speed readings]");
    so_destroy_ds(data);
    return 0;
}  // end main

const char* so_build_mask(unsigned n)
{
    if (n == 0) return NULL;
    const char*  prefix = "%d %d %lf";
    char*        field  = " %lf";
    const size_t size =
        1 + sizeof(prefix) + n * sizeof(" %lf");
    char* mask = malloc(size);
    strcpy(mask, prefix);
    if (mask == NULL) return NULL;
    char*  p   = mask + 1 + sizeof(prefix);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
    {
        char* pf = field;
        do {
            *p++ = *pf++;
        } while (*pf != 0);
    };
    *p = 0;  // terminate string 'mask'
    return mask;
}

Speed_data* so_cnvrt(const char* ln)
{
    if (ln == NULL) return NULL;  // no data
    const char* mask =
        "\
%d %d %lf\
%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf\
 %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf";
    Speed_data* one = malloc(sizeof(Speed_data));
    if (one == NULL) return NULL;
    int res = sscanf(
        ln, mask, &one->location_id, &one->speed_limit,
        &one->latest_average, &one->reading[0],
        &one->reading[1], &one->reading[2],
        &one->reading[3], &one->reading[4],
        &one->reading[5], &one->reading[6],
        &one->reading[7], &one->reading[8],
        &one->reading[9]);
    if (res != 13)
    {
        free(one);
        return NULL;
    };
    one->avg = 0.;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
        one->avg += one->reading[i];
    one->avg /= 10;
    return one;
}

Data_set* so_create_ds(unsigned n_rcd)
{  // return a data set for 'n_rcd'records of
   // 10 readings each
    if (n_rcd == 0) return NULL;
    Data_set* ds   = malloc(sizeof(Data_set));
    ds->size       = n_rcd;
    ds->n_readings = 10;
    ds->rcd        = malloc(ds->size * sizeof(Speed_data));
    return ds;
}

Data_set* so_destroy_ds(Data_set* ds)
{
    if (ds == NULL) return NULL;
    if (ds->rcd != NULL) free(ds->rcd);
    free(ds);
    return NULL;
};

int so_show(Data_set* set, const char* msg)
{
    if (set == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    %d lines in this set:\n\n", set->size);

    const char* l0 =
        "|-----------------------------------------------|";
    const char* l1 =
        "|          |          |         average         |";
    const char* l2 =
        "|    loc   |    lim   |    latest  |   actual   |";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", l0, l1, l2, l0);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < set->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf(
            "|    %3d   |    %3d   |   %6.2f   |    %6.2f  "
            "|\n",
            set->rcd[i].location_id,
            set->rcd[i].speed_limit,
            set->rcd[i].latest_average, set->rcd[i].avg);
    }
    printf("%s\n\n", l0);
    return 0;
}

int so_show_points(Data_set* set, const char* msg)
{
    if (set == NULL) return -1;
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s", msg);
    printf("    %d lines in this set:\n\n", set->size);
    const char* l0 =
        "|-------------------------------------------------"
        "--------------------------------------------------"
        "--------------------|";
    const char* l1 =
        "|     |     |      average    |                   "
        "                                                  "
        "                    |";
    const char* l2 =
        "| loc | lim | latest | actual | s p e e d   r e a "
        "d i n g s                                         "
        "                    |";
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", l0, l1, l2, l0);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < set->size; i += 1)
    {
        printf(
            "| %3d | %3d | %6.2f | %6.2f |",
            set->rcd[i].location_id,
            set->rcd[i].speed_limit,
            set->rcd[i].latest_average, set->rcd[i].avg);
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < set->n_readings; j += 1)
            printf(" %6.2f |", set->rcd[i].reading[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("%s\n\n", l0);
    return 0;
};
```

It is not a complete solution, but may be a way to go.

Comment: Memory leak... And possible memory corruption, too...

Comment: The code in your "answer" could be more useful if you could proof read it before posting. "More problems?" The function `so_build_mask()` is present, but is never called. That's probably a good thing, because it contains `strcpy()` after `malloc()` but before the verification that `malloc()` succeeded... And, what's with several spurious semi-colons scattered around? Why?

Comment: Stop and think. The number of *format specifiers* in a *format string* (that you call a "*mask*") has to be `<=` the number of variables being assigned in any call to `scanf()`. Adding a buggy function to assemble the string in allocated memory is not a good idea. Especially when the function calling `scanf()` is, itself, called in a loop. Talk about inefficient! A bad example of how **not** to do things. (Congratulations on plugging the memory leaks of version 1.)

Comment: I, too, can imagine an infinite number of alternative realities... What's your point? (Your example of unused code, `so_build_mask()` still has the issue of using `mask` _before_ verifying the success of the allocation... (If there are a varying number of fields on each row of data, then `scanf()` will not serve...)

Comment: "_Yes I did not check for success of an allocation of 40-less bytes in a SO answer._" Oh, but the code **does** check!! Just not in the right place... It's your uncorrected buggy code that is annoying.